# Custom parameter validator in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, customvalidator

I have created a custom validator to validate the String passed to the function in converter. However, the custom validator is not being called. Am I missing something?

***OperationParameter.java***

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = OperationParameterValidation.class)
@Target( { ElementType.PARAMETER
        })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface OperationParameter {
    String message() default "Operation Parameter Invalid";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

***OperationParameterValidation.java***

```
public class OperationParameterValidation implements ConstraintValidator<OperationParameter, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       System.out.println("Validator called");
        // validation process
        // return true / false;
    }

}
```

***converter.java***

```
@Component
public class StringToOperation implements Converter<String, Operation> {

    @Override
    public Operation convert(@Valid @OperationParameter String source) {
         // Even I pass wrong String this function is executed successfully, and no print from validator
    }
}
```

***Service.java***

```
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    ConversionService conversionService;

    public void action() {

        String action = "";
        Operation addInsertOperation = conversionService.convert(action, Operation.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that You mark `StringToOperation` as a `@Component`? Then Spring's validation will take place

Comment: I tried that but still not calling the validation.

Comment: Also can You show `ConversionService` class with the part where You create/inject `StringToOperation` converter?

Comment: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService is autowired and based on the argument it will be automatically called.

Comment: I think `ConversionService` and `StringToOperation` are not the same thing. Also arguments don't fit. I assume You inject `StringToOperation` into `ConversionService` using `@Autowired`. But can You put this code here? Just to crosscheck

Comment: conversionService.convert(...) function in the Service.java is getting called that means the binding is proper. Just for the infomration, I have added the formatter into FormatterRegistry in my config file which is taking care of the binding.

Comment: Does it work if you annotate the `StringToOperation` class with `@Validated`?

Comment: I tried putting @Validated but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Set `@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)` on validator class

Comment: If you mean putting the aforementioned annotation on my OperationParameterValidator class, then that did not work. Still, my isValid(...) function is not being called.